# Is it possible to add a WCF Web service reference to the .NET Application in IIS production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, production-environment

We have an ERP Application developed in .NET 3.5.

Recently I've developed a WCF Service to expose data retrieved from our business client's DB server.

Now I've added a service reference in my local consumer project and tested.

To put this application in production environment, we have to compile DLL every time and then publish in live.

I like to avoid the whole DLL compilation process where I have to depend on my developers team to acquire code and compile. (This issue is because of not using a TFS or VSS to work on single solution file)

So I'd like to know whether one can add a service reference & class file to the project which is in production environment at IIS root directory without recompilation of the consumer assembly.

Comment: *Recently I've developed a WCF Service to retrieve data from a client* - this makes no sense. Usually a client retrieves data from a service.

Comment: Client in sense our  business client's server. I'll replace the word  with server @TomRedfern

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what it is you are wanting to avoid here, but it sppears you'd like to be able to add code to an existing application without rebuilding/redeploying that application. This is called hot-swapping.

However, service references are code. Therefore they need to be compiled, along with the consuming code, into one or more assemblies. This is the nature of consuming web services using a service reference.

You could use reflection to load code at runtime which would allow [hot-swapping](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18729/Loading-and-Unloading-an-Assembly-at-Runtime) of an old with a new dll, but the new service reference would still need to be compiled into the new DLL.

A better way of approaching this would be to not use service references at all, but call the service directly using [ChannelFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows you to call a service without using the service metadata to generate a service reference.

Now, WCF respects something called [Data Contract Equivalence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734767(v=vs.110).aspx), which roughly translated means that a service will respect a passed type providing the type passed looks the same as a type exposed as an argument by the service.

What this means is that your development team can, based on the types defined in the service, create their own equivalent types, and then call the service passing (or receiving) these types as if they were native service types.

However, this does not remove the requirement that all this will need to be compiled at some point. What it does do is remove the coupling between consumer and service.

> Can you provide clarity on which scenarios does hot swapping /
>   ChannelFactory are beneficial to use

While this won't directly address your requirement,

Hot-swapping is useful for changing the behavior applications at run time. This is important if:

1. your application is a black box,
2. you need 100% availability, or
3. your deployment process is so arduous that the cost of deploying new versions is prohibitive.

ChannelFactory is beneficial in many ways, but basically it removes the requirement to generate service references, which, while ultimately deterministic, can be unpredictable and generally increase complexity.

ChannelFactory also enables you to then take advantage of data contract equivalence, which further decouples the consumer from the service. If, for example, the service contract changes to add a new field to a type, then the consumer can generally continue calling the service without change.

Comment: We don't use a TFS in our development environment, so all the developers will not have the up to date code in their project, we always combine the code to create final project, then compile and publish. This is a tedious process, which I want to avoid. But your answer proves that compilation is mandatory at any point of time with or without consuming the service.  I'm new to hot-swapping , ChannelFactory & Data Contract Equivalence. Will explore and learn about them. Can you provide clarity on which scenarios does hot swapping / ChannelFactory are beneficial to use.

Comment: Interesting to know, I may not be able implement this in my current scenario. As I have to follow my project managers approach. I will try out ChannelFactory on other projects which are still in development stage.

Comment: Are there any other possible solutions to this. If not i'm left with only single old solution to publish my service along with application.

Comment: @Sri - sorry nothing else I can think of.

Comment: Refern --  This may be only possible solution, I couldn't find any other.